# Winform DataGridView UserAddedRow to add a new row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

It is possible to use event UserAddedRow to add a new row ?
When it is, do you have an example ?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: please show some code... what have you tried ? what does/doesn't work ? if there were exceptions/error - show them too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UserAddedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.useraddedrow.aspx) event is fired after row added. You can not use it to add something, as it fires `after` somethign already was added.

According to msdn:

> Occurs when the user has finished adding a row to the DataGridView
>   control.

Comment: Thanks you, How can i add a new row Then ?

Comment: I would say use databinding via DataTable like in msdn example. Check it out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx. Read entire article by the way, not only code example.

Comment: Thanks you for your respone, but how can i retrive the NEW value of the Rows ?

Comment: in the Event: e.Row.Cells[index].value

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using data binding, you have to add the columns and rows manually.

```
dgvApplications.Columns.Add("Col1", "Column 1");
dgvApplications.Columns.Add("Col2", "Column 2");
dgvApplications.Rows.Add("Col1Value", "Col2Value");
```

But data binding is usually the better option.

```
BindingList<Application> applications = new BindingList<Application>();
dgvApplications.DataSource = applications;
// set AutoGenerateColumns to false and manually add columns to get pretty column names.
// set AutoGenerateColumns to true to not worry about adding columns in early prototyping
dgvModules.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Then if `Application` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` you can do something like this:

```
applications.Add(new Application{ File="blah.txt" };
```

The property changed notification will allow the grid to automatically update when the underlying model is changed.

The data binding option helps decouple your GUI from your data. 
"Model-View-Controller" design pattern helps you later if you need to redesign the GUI, or add a secondary interface such as the web or phone app.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx